# Trouble getting filepicker.io drag-drop pane working using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, filepicker.io

I'm having trouble getting my filepicker.io "drag-drop pane" working using javascript.  I already had the filepicker.io html widget working similar to:

```
<input type="filepicker-dragdrop" data-fp-drag-class="filepicker_dragdrop"/>
```

However, I'm having trouble calling filepicker.io from JavaScript.  When I drag a file into the 'div.filepicker_dragdrop' container, nothing happens.  Any thoughts?

In my form .html.erb:

```
<div class="filepicker_dragdrop"></div>
```

In my .css file:

```
.filepicker_dragdrop {
  padding: 8px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

In my filepicker_dragdrop.js:

```
filepicker.makeDropPane($('.filepicker_dragdrop')[0], {
    multiple: true,
    dragEnter: function() {
        $(".filepicker_dragdrop").html("Drop to upload").css({
            'backgroundColor': "#E0E0E0",
            'border': "1px solid #000"
        });
    },
    dragLeave: function() {
        $(".filepicker_dragdrop").html("Drop files here").css({
            'backgroundColor': "#F6F6F6",
            'border': "1px dashed #666"
        });
    },
    onSuccess: function(fpfiles) {
        $(".filepicker_dragdrop").text("Done, see result below");
        $("#localDropResult").text(JSON.stringify(fpfiles));
    },
    onError: function(type, message) {
        $("#localDropResult").text('('+type+') '+ message);
    },
    onProgress: function(percentage) {
        $(".filepicker_dragdrop").text("Uploading ("+percentage+"%)");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using both the makeDropPane and the drag-drop widget together?  You should only be using one of them, as they may be conflicting trying to grab the drop event

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still, just been bitten. Make sure you call the makeDropPane function **after** the document is loaded!